# Laravel 5.8 foreign key migration error - "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: foreign-keys, migration, laravel-5.8

I need to create foreign key to join table books with table users. I know that user_id column has to be the same type also unsigned if origin col is unsigned but it should be ok. Both table are bigint(20) unsigned. But I am getting an error: "**Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed**"

Here is the migration code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index()->after('id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('SET NULL')->onUpdate('CASCADE');
    });
}
```

and here is the users table migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Can somebody tell me please where is the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by default MariaDB MyIsam engine for tables. So I needed to restart db with new my.ini which defaults to InnoDB and then migrate all tables again.